# Using PHP within jQuery for links to images stored in the WordPress template directory

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying hard to figure this out. I basically just want to add an image (external.png) to the end of links that are external. I'm putting the image in a directory called img stored in my wordpress theme. If my src to the image is direct it works, but I'd rather use:

```
<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>
```

When putting it right into the after() didn't work I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var templateDir = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>";
$('a').filter(function() {
return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
}).after('<img src="' + templateDir + '/img/external.png" />');
```

});

But that didn't work either. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: jQuery works, as it's JavaScript, on the client side, not the server. What does your jQuery look like once it's rendered to the browser? (Use 'view source' and paste the relevant part of the jQuery here into the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wordpress, the correct way to insert php vars into javascript is through `wp_localize_script()`. In your Functions.php (or a plugin, of whatever).

```
<?php
$data = array( 'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $data );
?>
```

When called, `wp_localize_script()` creates a global JS object that you can then retrieve variables from at runtime (on the client side - use Firebug to check out the JS dom to ensure that this is happeneing).

```
<script>
alert(object_name.some_string); // alerts 'Some string to translate'
</script>
```

The point is, you must define PHP variables on the server, before they are available on the client side.

Alternately, you could hack something out with ajax. [But the former solution is the preferred method in WP](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

Cheers

Comment: Glad to help - if you think this answer is correct, don't forget to "accept" it ;D